# How can I convert a cell array to a sparse matrix?

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert an Excel spreadsheet ([link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0203Ere93H4cC1PM3JJU3BLSm8&authuser=0)) to a MATLAB sparse matrix.

How can I import it to MATLAB as a working sparse matrix? So far, all I've been able to do is convert it to a cell array...
I tried to convert my name matrix first with this function:

```
function [names,links]=Changing(WorldReligion)
i=0;
names={};
for i=1:337
        if WorldReligion(i,1)~=WorldReligion(i+1,1)
        names(i)=WorldReligion(i,1);
    end

end
```

However, I get this error:

```
[names , links]=Changing(WorldReligion) Undefined function 'ne' for
input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you just need to use curly brackets {} to access the cell _content_ instead of the cell itself. i.e. What if you use WorldReligion{i,1} ~= WorldReligion{i+1,1} ?

Comment: Error using  ~= 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 0):

That's a short answer because it looked bad as a comment, but if you want to fetch the unique religion names from your spreadsheet, you can use the [unique](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?searchHighlight=unique) function which works on cell arrays of strings. In your case to get the 1st column of the spreadsheet, use this:

```
clear
clc

[~, text, ~] = xlsread('WorldReligion.xlsx');

UniqueNames = unique(text(:,1));

whos
```

Output of `whos`:

```
Name               Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

  UniqueNames      117x1              15654  cell               
  text             388x10            452500  cell
```

This retrieves the 117 unique names form the 1st column of the 'text' data, which I think is what you wanted to do with the above for-loop. Is that the case?

Comment: @user3316789 so did you try my suggestion??